# iOS overrides the `navBarButtonColor` when using PNGs

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, react-native-navigation, wix-react-native-navigation

#### Issue Description

In my application I have a navigation bar search button set up as follows:

```
static navigatorButtons = {
    leftButtons: [
        {
            id: 'back-nav-button',
            icon: require('../assets/images/icons/arrow-left.png')
        }
   ]
};
```

The button works as intended on both iOS and Android, but the button is blue on iOS. I understand that this is the desired behavior and that the color can be overridden by setting `navBarButtonColor`, but the problem is that it's a multi-colored button - meaning I want then button to simply contain the PNG image's colors, and not the `navBarButtonColor`.

I've tried setting `navBarButtonColor` to `null`, `transparent`, but nothing seems to work.

So my question is, is there a way to make navigation bar icons take on the color of the PNG provided, as is the case on Android?

#### Steps to Reproduce / Code Snippets / Screenshots

Simply run any RNN app on iOS with a simple `static navigatorButtons = ...` using a local multi-colored PNG and you'll see the colors of the icon get overwritten.

---

#### Environment

- React Native Navigation version: 1.1.473
- React Native version: 0.55.3
- Platform(s) (iOS, Android, or both?): iOS
- Device info (Simulator/Device? OS version? Debug/Release?): Android Emulator on Debug

Answer (score 2):

On iOS, `UIBarButtonItem` uses images created with source image's alpha channel. To display the actual image (not an alpha channel mask of it) you need to change your image's rendering mode to `alwaysOriginal`

Although, looking at [React Native Image class documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/image) I can't see `renderingMode` property

Answer (score 0):

We've managed to find a workaround for this. By setting the `disableIconTint` button property to `true`, it disables the icon color override. See the following example:

```
static navigatorButtons = {
    leftButtons: [
        {
            id: 'back-nav-button',
            icon: require('../assets/images/icons/arrow-left.png'),
            disableIconTint: true // Add this line to use the PNG's color
        }
   ]
};
```